# Sencha EXTJS and MVC pattern

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs

I am coming up to speed on modifying an application built in EXT,and I would like to use an MVC pattern with the overall architecture. Could someone point out how I can load views dynamically in EXT? For instance, to make a blind call to a controller that will return some kind of view that could be html, a grid, a window, etc...

I'm open to a javascript only solution, or one that calls and retrieves views from asp.net mvc.

thanks

Comment: Not an answer per se, but have a peek here for another angle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560175/presentation-patterns-to-use-with-ext-js/3564150#3564150

Comment: I guess that's what I am doing already. Passing in a json serialized viewmodel and handling it that way. I guess right now there is not a lot of community guidance as far as a specific "best way" to code up extjs UIs.  Thanks again for the link though.